# Extract ID from an URL with RegExp

Tags: regex, typescript

I have this kind of Url : 
`/clients/18378/offers/2219/items/32779`

I'm  trying to get an array with in it : `18378`, `2219`, `32779`

I've try this code but unsuccessful :

```
let currentUrl = this.router.url; // = '/clients/18378/offers/2219/items/32779'
var regexRouteOffer = /\/clients\/(.*?)\/offers\/(.*?)\/items\/(.*?)/gm;
var match = currentUrl.match(regexArticleInOffer);
console.log("Test 1 >>", match); // => ["/clients/18378/offers/2219/items/"]
```

I've try with `exec` function but it give me only one of the number (first one only)

```
var matches = [];
for (var m = null; m = regexRouteOffer.exec(currentUrl); matches.push(m[1]));
console.log("Test 2 >> ", matches); //["18378"]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You asked to get the first capture only with `m[1]`. If you need the rest, use `m[2]`, `m[3]`... Note you must replace all the `.*?` with `[^\/]+`.

Comment: Assuming the url contains all strings, and only these numbers appears, you can use **[^a-z\/]+** which will get all numbers.

for the record, Wiktor is right, but i commented another pattern just for example purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the flags `g` (because you only want to match once), and `m` (because there's no need to turn on multiline mode). And finally the last `.*` is ungreedy, so it tries to match as few elements as possible (zero in this case), so remove all or at least the final `?`.

```
let currentUrl = '/clients/18378/offers/2219/items/32779'
var regexRouteOffer = /\/clients\/(.*)\/offers\/(.*)\/items\/(.*)/;
var match = currentUrl.match(regexRouteOffer);
console.log(match[1]); // 18378
console.log(match[2]); // 2219
console.log(match[3]); // 32779
```